# K&R Exercise 1-13

Tags: c

The exercise is to

"Write a program to print a histogram of the lengths of words in its input."

Here's the answer given in the C Answer Book. For some reason it doesn't work in CodeBlocks as there isn't any output when I enter my input. Why is this so?

Another question is with regards to `wl[i]`; what is that?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXHIST 15
#define MAXWORD 11
#define IN      1
#define OUT     0

main()
{
    int c, i, nc, state;
    int len;
    int maxvalue;
    int ovflow;
    int wl[MAXWORD];

    state = OUT;
    nc = 0;
    ovflow = 0;
    for(i=0; i < MAXWORD; ++i)
        wl[i] = 0;
    while(( c = getchar()) !=EOF) {
        if (c==' '|| c=='\n'|| c == '\t' ){
            state = OUT;
            if (nc>0)
                if (nc < MAXWORD)
                    ++wl[nc];
                else
                    ++ovflow;

            nc=0;
        }else if (state == OUT){
            state = IN;
            nc = 1;
        }else
            ++nc;
    }
    maxvalue = 0;
    for (i = 1; 1<MAXWORD; ++i)
        if (wl[i] > maxvalue)
            maxvalue = wl[i];

    for (i=1; i<MAXWORD; ++i){
        printf("%5d - %5d : ", i, wl[i]);
        if (wl[i]> 0){
            if ((len=wl[i] * MAXHIST / maxvalue) <=0)
                len = 1;
        }else
            len = 0;
        while (len > 0 ) {
            putchar('*');
            --len;
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    if (ovflow > 0)
            printf("There are %d words >= %d\n", ovflow, MAXWORD);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried compiling with *all* warnings enabled?

Comment: You need to actually read some books on C if you are asking questions like what is an array subscript. You'll never solve your problem if you don't understand what you're doing.

Comment: Doesn't K&R count as a book on C? Thanks for clarifying, didn't know that was an array subscript. @Kevin I've enabled all warnings but I'm still facing the same issue.

Comment: Yes, K&R2 counts as a book.  But, since it explains array subscript notation quite early on, the fact that you ask about the meaning of `wl[i]` leaves people concerned that even if you are reading the book, you aren't learning from it.

Answer (score 3):

This line is wrong:

```
for (i = 1; 1 < MAXWORD; ++i)
```

The second `1` should be `i`, of course.  It will be a long time before `1` is not less than `11`.  On the other hand, you then go reading all over memory, and sooner or later, you're going to read something unreadable, and the program should then crash.  There's a chance that it won't crash, but the behaviour is undefined so anything that happens is OK.